# According to Plato, can there be forms for a certain class of particulars?

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle, plato, ancient-philosophy, greeks

In the beginning of Parmenides, Plato seems to think that most, or possibly all, particulars do not have corresponding forms; but he is not very explicit about why. My question is, does it not make sense to say that there exists a quintessential example (form) for a certain class of particulars, that all these particulars resemble? Or can a form only be a non-particular predicated of particulars?

Comment: Plato's forms are not "quintessential examples", they are properties that particulars partake in, not objects they resemble. And partaking is the way that particulars gain their properties. So if there is some sort of "essence" to your class of particulars there will be a form they partake in responsible for it. According to some interpretations of Phaedo, Plato even admits that there are individualized form-copies particulars partake in, singular rather than general properties, like beauty-of-Helen, mediating that partaking, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-metaphysics/#8).

Comment: @Conifold, as far as I am concerned, the idea that Platonic ideas are just properties is an Aristotelian interpretation of the Theory of the Ideas. There is constantly an ongoing debate whether ideas are mere properties or rather entities with a different nature.

Comment: @Josh Abel- Your question on how philosophy can support science was closed, so I had to reach you here. One example of how philosophy can support science can be found on my website;  charlessaunders5.academia.edu  The paper is titled; Deductive Theory/Inductive Method and was posted two days ago. Just read the Abstract and decide whether to read it or not. If you do read it and would like to comment, you will find my email address inside any of the four books that are uploaded there. The address is on one of the first few pages. Your question was appropriate. Cheers, Charles M. Saunders